# Subset specific columns

Tags: r

My sample data is

```
DF
x.c  y.ce  z.ac
```

These are all numeric columns

I am trying to extract column `c` alone.
If i use grep or grepl it takes all the columns as all of them contains `c`.

Could you please help me to solve an issue.
Thank you.

Comment: why not just `DF[,c("c","tg")]` ?

Comment: Because cols in my DF have actually more complex names,e.g. abc.c and cde.ce and I'm trying to pick only those which have c alone at the end of the name.

Comment: You can use `grepl("\\b(c|tg)\\b", names(DF))`

Comment: 'c alone that the end of the name': then i'd say `grepl("c$", names(DF))`

Comment: @rbm it returns a list of TRUE FALSE, but i want to keep values of those columns as well

Comment: @akrun it returns a list of TRUE FALSE, but i want to keep values of those columns as well

Comment: then just `names(DF)[grepl("c$", names(DF))]`

Comment: @rbm it returns now only list of names but not values of those columns which names contains c

Comment: You have to subset using that index. i.e. `DF[, grepl(...`

Comment: This is going in circles. Please take a deep breath, provide a small reproducible example and expected result you want to see.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment above, if you want to get the names that **end** with `c` you'd want to get them via

```
names(DF)[grepl("c$", names(DF))]
```

and then get the values via

```
DF[, names(DF)[grepl("c$", names(DF))]]
```

(or just the TRUE/FALSE index:

```
DF[, grepl("c$", names(DF))]
```

)

Update:

OP has changed the original question, so the answer is now a simply

```
DF[, "c"]
```

to extract the `c` column

```
> DF <- data.frame(c=c(1,2,3), ce=c(2,3,4), ac=c(3,4,5))
> DF
  c ce ac
1 1  2  3
2 2  3  4
3 3  4  5
> DF[,"c"]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Update 2:
OP has again changed the original question, so the answer now is:

```
 DF <- data.frame(x.c=c(1,2,3), y.ce=c(2,3,4), z.ac=c(3,4,5))
> DF
  x.c y.ce z.ac
1   1    2    3
2   2    3    4
3   3    4    5
> DF[, names(DF)[grepl("\\.c$", names(DF))]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: Your code is working but it takes into account other columns containing `c` in the column names. For example it takes columns `c` and `fc` because the latter also has c in the names. But i want instead only c alone

Comment: You said 'c' at the end, that is what `c$` means. Do you only want columns named `c` ?

Comment: You can't have two columns in data.frame with the same name, can you? In which case no need for regex, but plain `names(DF)=="c"` i'd have thought

Comment: @rbm yes but in my example data frame i showed that i have some columns ending with `c` and `ce` for example. By using `c$` i will get both of them as both contain c actually.

Comment: No way - `c$` means `c` is at the end of the string, it will not mach `ce`. If will match `c`, `ac`, `aaaac`, `cccccacacac`, etc.

Comment: In which case you just need `DF[, "c"]`

Comment: phew, got there in the end.